# std::binary_search doesn't work as expected

Tags: algorithm, vector, binary-search

I tried making a program that checks if a number is in a vector using `std::binary_search`

I know I could've used `std::find`, but I heard `std::binary_search` if a lot faster than `std::find`, so I wanted to learn to use it if I ever need to check if a number is in a container.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> v(n);

    std::cout << "Enter the elements: ";
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int &x)
    {
        std::cin >> x;
    });

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;

    bool doesItExist = std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), number);

    if(doesItExist == false)
    {
        std::cout << "It doesn't exist!";
    }
    else std::cout << "It exists!";

    return 0;
}
```

I thought `std::binary_search` should return `true` if a number is found in a container.

Now I will explain with few examples what happens with my code

In all following examples I will use 10 elements:

```
Enter number of elements: 10
Enter the elements: 1 10 100 -11 -112 -17 44 -99 99 558
```

1°

```
Enter a number: 1
It doesn't exist!
```

2°

```
Enter a number: 10
It doesn't exist!
```

It will continue like this until I enter one of the last two numbers (`99` or `558`)

Pre last number:

```
Enter a number: 99
It exists!
```

Last number:

```
Enter a number: 558
It exists!
```

I am not sure why this happens. 
If anyone could explain why this happens, why do only last 2 numbers work?
And what would be a fix for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the way the [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) works: you cannot enter numbers in arbitrary order, and expect `binary_search` to find a match; the items in the range must be ordered. That is the assumption the binary search makes when deciding which way to go from the middle, right or left.

If you add this line to your code after reading the data, the problem will be fixed:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Also if you enter the numbers in sorted order, your code will work without modifications:

```
-112 -99 -17 -11 1 10 44 99 100 558
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the reason that numbers need to be sorted in order for `binary_search` to work?

Comment: @ihatestrings Binary search is the approach that you use to find a word in a dictionary. Now imagine applying the same approach when the dictionary is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

usually binary search is applied on the sorted vectors or arrays

ur's appears to be not sorted.

sort the vector then re-examine the result.